# checkbox call another mutation when false

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

```
<li v-for='item in resultQuery' :key='item.id'>    
 <label class='custom-checkbox'>
   <input type='checkbox' :value='item' v-model='checkBrands'>
   <span @click='loadProducts(item.seoName)>{{ item.title }} 
   </span>
 </label>
</li>
```

In `checkBrands`, my brand names are transferred.
When click on the checkbox, a mutation is called, which loads the products (api).

```
      if(this.checkBrands != 0) {
        this.$store.commit(
          'showFilteredList',
          response.data.items
        );
      } else {
        this.$store.commit(
          'deleteCheckboxItems',
          response.data.items
        );
      }
```

If the checkbox is false, I would like to call another mutation. (which clears the list) How do I call another mutation when false, and how should I track if false?

**filter.js**

```
  state: {
   filteredBrands: []
  },

  mutations: {
   showFilteredList(state, payload) {
    state.filteredBrands.payload;
     if(payload.length < 1) {
      return;
     }
    state.filteredBrands.push(...payload);
   },

   deleteCheckboxItems(state, checkboxValue) {
    state.filteredBrands = state.filteredBrands.filter((item) => 
      item.id == checkboxValue);
    }
   }
```

**upd**

There are several checkboxes. If `showFilteredList` checkbox is selected, everything works. When pressed, mutation `showFilteredList` is called (checkbox true), when pressed again (false), products are deleted from `store.filteredbrands.`

Can't do: the right condition is to be applied to each checkbox.

And condition `this.checkBrands != 0` incorrect, since they will check the length of the array. (id)

Answer (score 1):

Hi you can use `checkBrands` and say that  at `data(){return {checkBrands: null}}` to determine what method you want

```
<input 
  type="checkbox" 
  :value="item.title" <--- its not value it is :value
   v-model="checkBrands" <----- its not :v-model it is v-model
@click="checkBrands === true ? loadProducts('1st method') : someOtherMethod('2nd method')"
>
```

And at:

```
import { mapMutaions } from 'vuex' ,<--- dont forget this import
export default {
  data(){
    return{
     ...
    }
  },
methods:{
...mapMutation(['oneMutation', 'secondMutation']),

     loadProducts(item){
       this.oneMutation()
       console.log('loadproducts', item);
     },

     someOtherMethod(item){
       this.secondMutation()
       console.log('otherproducts', item);
     }
}
```

Or you can do `@click="loadProducts()"` and then at `loadProducts` method you can determine what mutation yo want to call based on `checkBrands` prop.

```
loadProducts(){
 if(this.checkBrands === true){
    this.oneMutation()
}else{
    this.secondMutation()
}
```

Comment: Can you do it like this?  
<input type="checkbox" :value="checkBrands" v-model="boolValue"
boolValue: null,
checkBrands: 'adidas', or arrays or brands

and I item will be shoes, sneakers etc?

Comment: I can't change ```v-model``` need to transfer the array to the parent :c Maybe there is a way to have a second v-model?

Comment: I am confused what is `item` and `checkBrands`. If you had already added values to them, they wont change, you can always access them  if they are in data() or computed property. 

If you want show me data(), and describe what you want to do with input(I don't mean changing mutation on true false) and i can try to do it and send you.

Comment: Updated the question. (I made some progress)